# mantener ventana emergente después de enviar datos desde una tabla a inputs(PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando una pagina la cual tienen una ventana emergente que muestra una tabla y su contenido, ademas posee un botón [add] el cual al presionar envía la información a los inputs de abajo. el problema es que si lo consigo realizar. pero se me cierra la ventana emergente y se recarga la pagina. me gustaría saber como le hago para que cuando presione el botón [add] los datos se pasen a los inputs y no se recargue la pagina.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente ejecuto todo dentro de un unico archivo llamado **arbol.php**

esta es la manera con la que cargo mi tabla

```
<table id="tablaInsumos" class="tablaInsumos" style="font-size: 9px;" >
<thead style="background-color:#217346;text-align:center;color:#fff;">
    <tr>

        <th title="Nombre Insumo">INSUMO</th>
        <th title="Unidad de Medicion de Insumo">MEDIDA</th>
        <th title="Valor por Unidad de medida de Insumo">VALOR</th>
        <th title="Proveedor de Insumo">PROVEEDOR</th>
        <th style="visibility: hidden; width:0px;" title="Nombre Insumo">ID</th>


        <th title="Acciones">ACCIONES</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody border-collapse: collapse #006699;  style="background-color:#EAECED;font-size:9px;">
<?php
        $query     = "SELECT * FROM vista_insumos ORDER BY Nombre" ;
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <form method="POST" action="arbol.php">

        <td><?php echo $row['Nombre'] ?></td>
        <td ><?php echo $row['Medida'] ?></td>
        <td>$<?php echo number_format($row['Valor'], 2, ",", ".")?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Proveedor'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['ID'] ?></td>
        <td><a style="height:32px; font-size:14px;" class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" href="arbol.php?idInsumos=<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>"></a>



        </td>
        </form>
    </tr><?php
  }

        ?>

</tbody>
```

luego de esta manera ago para obtener los datos al presionar el boton [add]

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['idInsumos'])) {
  $idInsumos       = $_GET['idInsumos']; 
  $query     = "SELECT * FROM insumos_eiser WHERE idInsumos ='$idInsumos'"; 
  $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1) {

    $row             = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
    $nombreInsumos             = $row['nombreInsumos'];  
    $tipoCantidad =$row['tipoCantidad'];
    $valor =$row['valor'];
  }
} ?>
```

y por ultimo los cargo dentro de el formulario que corresponde a la parte de abajo que se muestra en la imagen

```
<form action="#">
    <div style="float: left; padding:12px;">
    <label>Nombre Insumo:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="nombreInsumo" readonly value="<?php echo $nombreInsumos; ?>" placeholder="Nombre Insumo">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; padding:12px;">
    <label>Unidad Medicion:</label><br>
    <input type="text" readonly name="nombreInsumo" value="<?php echo $tipoCantidad; ?>" placeholder="Nombre Insumo">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; padding:12px;">
    <label>valor:</label><br>
    <input type="text"  readonly name="nombreInsumo" value="<?php echo $valor; ?>" placeholder="Nombre Insumo">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; padding:12px;">
    <label>Cantidad:</label><br>
    <input type="number" name="nombreInsumo" placeholder="Nombre Insumo">
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; padding:12px;">
    <label>Total:</label><br>
    <input type="text"  readonly name="nombreInsumo" placeholder="Nombre Insumo">
    </div><br>
    <div style="float: left; padding:12px;">

    <input type="submit" name="guardarInsumo"  value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success">
    </div>
  </form>
```

e buscado información y se que se utiliza ajax pero en los ejemplos solo imprimen mensajes y no envían variables como seria en este caso. si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Sugeriría que uses Ajax para esto. Eso evitaría que la página tenga que recargarse e incluso puedes incorporar la ventana emergente a un contenedor de la misma página, manejando así una sola interfaz de usuario. Hoy día con la existencia de Ajax una ventana emergente no tiene razón de ser, ya no estamos en los años 90 en los que Windows puso de moda esto de las ventanas emergentes. Desde el punto de vista de la experiencia de usuario es mucho mejor una interfaz integrada y dinámica.